# React-Bootstrap Definitely Typed: Error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap, typescript-typings

I've just upgraded typings for react-bootstrap and I'm getting error:

> Error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

on this line:

```
declare namespace ReactBootstrap {
    // Import React
    import React = __React;
    //definitions omitted
}

declare module "react-bootstrap" {
    export = ReactBootstrap; //Error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.
}
```

Is the definition file wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in my case I had previously written my own definitions, because they were missing from the definitely typed typings:

**custom.d.ts:**

```
declare module "react-bootstrap" {
    // Import React
    import React = require("react");

    // <InputGroup.Addon>
    interface InputGroupAddonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes {
    }
    class InputGroupAddon extends React.Component<InputGroupAddonProps, {}> {
    }
}
```

the definitions from definitely typed was previously looking like this:

```
declare module "react-bootstrap" {
    // Import React
    import React = require("react");
    //all typings listed here
}
```

but this has changed to:

```
declare namespace ReactBootstrap {
    // Import React
    import React = __React;
    //all typings listed here, including InputGroupAddon which was previously missing
}

declare module "react-bootstrap" {
    export = ReactBootstrap;
}
```

I fixed the error by removing duplicate definitions from custom.d.ts